# Entity class creation on AWS Lamda

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices

We are planning to create a project using AWS Lamda Microservices. The concept behind the microservices are there will not be any connection to the any of the packages available in other microservices. In this structure we are thinking what will be the best structure for storing the Database Entity files. If we are storing the entity files on each micro services packages, the same Entity will be repeat in different microservices.

In our example Doctor.Java will have as an entity in almost all microservices. But if we have a change in doctor table we have to change this in all Microservices class too. Is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Aws lambda is a nano service when we say microservice we mean a list of available services, for example, AccountService might me be an example which is deployed in docker where we can call this service to

```
1.create an account
2.to delete an account 
3.to modify an account
```

Whereas in the case of aws Lamda it is a nano service for account service built with aws lambda will result in the creation of three nano services

```
   1.Lamda 1 -  create an account
   2.Lamda 2-  to delete an account
   3.Lambda 3 - to modify an account
```

when coming to your question of entity each microservice should have a separate database, separate entities no entity or code should be repeated. In your case, Doctor.java should be present in DoctorService microservice which will create, modify, delete no other service should modify the Doctor.java if there has to a change in Doctor table  it should be through the DoctorService microservice only